# Customizing order of joined cell + header values when cell value isn't blank in Google Sheets (1A)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

How can I modify the equation in this [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxe1hWgtzKwLXYGEmTP0OO7K9E1pp48nBBlTTk_p_-Y/edit?usp=sharing) so that a user can customize the order of header & Value pairs?

**Goal** 1: Order display based on the number before a header.
Goal 2: Don't display the header/value pair when there is no number present in the header (alt: when a wildcard value is presented before the header don't display)

This equation results in the following display

```
INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:D6="",,"♦"&A1:D1&" "&A2:D6)),,9^9)), "♦", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

However, it would be preferable if the order could be arranged based on providing an order in the header value like the following display where empty cells (where `ISBLANK=TRUE`) are not displayed (2 & 3). Also, the header/value pair for "History" are not displayed since a `_History` is provided in the column header without a number.

[image]

I believe the following formula related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741250/how-to-customize-order-of-header-values-that-are-joined-when-answer-is-yes-in-go), which reordered headers (but also did other functions) can be modified to achieve the desired function

```
INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A9:D10), FLATTEN(A8:D8), 1))="yes", 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SORT(FLATTEN(A8:D8))), "(^\d+_)", )&"", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

The shared spreadsheet is Google Spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxe1hWgtzKwLXYGEmTP0OO7K9E1pp48nBBlTTk_p_-Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(
 IF((A2:D4<>"")*(REGEXMATCH(A1:D1, "^\d+_")), "♥"&A1:D1&" "&A2:D4, )), 
 FLATTEN(A1:D1), 1), "\d+_", ),,9^9))), "♥", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

[image]